# How do you override the dependent behavior of an association that's inherited in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have these definitions:

```
module Votable
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      has_many :votes
    end
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Votable
end
```

The `Votable` module is included from a gem so I can't modify the source. I would like to override the default behavior of `:dependent => :nullify` to `:dependent => :destroy` as if it were like this:

```
class Post
  include Votable

  has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that... once you've included the module it's AR macros are going to be called. Did you try just specifying your `has_many :votes` line like you showed in your example? Maybe if a macro is called a second time it will override the previous call, I don't know. I suspect it would just raise an exception but it may be worth a shot.